# how to generate a new rows and adding 1 sec for datetime column based on specific duration

Tags: sql, azure

i've a data in sql azure as below and and trying loop and iterate a new Start_date column (let us called it "New_time") increasing by 1 sec based on the other column called (StatusDuration) and after that create a new column (let us called it "Interval") to round the new column of new time to the nearest interval of 15 min and finally group the date by (UserId,StatusKey,Interval) and count the new_time.

**The Date on SQL Azure looks like:-**

```
userid  statuskey   stateDuration   StatusDateTimeGMT   EndDateTimeGMT
Abanoub.Sanad   available   4656    2022-09-29 07:29:16 2022-09-29 08:46:52
Abanoub.Sanad   available   24626   2022-09-29 10:12:26 2022-09-29 17:02:52
Abanoub.Sanad   available   9030    2022-09-29 17:18:23 2022-09-29 19:48:53
Abanoub.Sanad   available   33647   2022-09-29 23:04:07 2022-09-30 08:24:54
```

**the output data that want to see it**

[image]

**the comparison between sql and excel query on the same logic**

[image]

**the used query**

```
with cte1 as(
select userid,statuskey,stateDuration,[StatusDateTimeGMT]+ '02:00' as StatusDateTimeGMT,[EndDateTimeGMT] + '02:00' as EndDateTimeGMT,
interval= cast(floor(cast([StatusDateTimeGMT]+ '02:00' as float)*(96))/(96) as datetime),
interval_end_date=cast(ceiling(cast([StatusDateTimeGMT]+ '02:00' as float)*(96))/(96) as datetime)
from AgentActivityLog
where [StatusDateTimeGMT]+'2:00'>= '2022-09-28' and [StatusDateTimeGMT]+'2:00' < '2022-09-30' and StateDuration > 0 and userid = 'Abanoub.Sanad'),
cte2 as(
select userid,statuskey,[EndDateTimeGMT],[StatusDateTimeGMT],interval,interval_end_date from cte1
union all
select userid,statuskey,[EndDateTimeGMT],interval_end_date,dateadd(second,900,interval),dateadd(second,900,interval_end_date) 
from cte2 
where dateadd(second,15,interval_end_date)< [EndDateTimeGMT])
select userid,statuskey,interval,
[Duration]= case 
when interval_end_date<[EndDateTimeGMT] then datediff(second,[StatusDateTimeGMT],interval_end_date)
else datediff(second,[StatusDateTimeGMT],[EndDateTimeGMT]) end
from cte2
ORDER BY interval
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried the sql script for the above requirement.

- sample source table is taken as in below image

[image: src_img]

**SQL Script**

- Use the Below SQL script
  **Method 1**

```
    with cte as(
    select userid,statuskey,stateDuration,cnt=0,[start_date],
    nearestdate= cast(floor(cast([start_date] as float)*(24*4))/(24*4) as smalldatetime) from src_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT userid,statuskey,stateDuration,cnt+1,dateadd(second,1,[start_date]),
    nearestdate= cast(floor(cast(dateadd(second,1,[start_date]) as float)*(24*4))/(24*4) as smalldatetime) from cte where cnt+1<stateDuration)
    (select distinct userid,statuskey,nearestdate,count(nearestdate)as count from cte group by userid,statuskey,nearestdate) 
    option (maxrecursion 0);
```

**Alternate approach-Method2**

```
    with cte1 as(
    select userid,statuskey,stateDuration,[start_date],
    nearestdate= cast(floor(cast([start_date] as float)*(24*4))/(24*4) as datetime),
    batch_end_date=cast(ceiling(cast([start_date] as float)*(24*4))/(24*4) as datetime),
    total_end_date=DATEADD(second,stateDuration,[start_date])
    from src_table
    ),
    cte2 as(
    select userid,statuskey,total_end_date,[start_date],nearestdate,batch_end_date from cte1
    union all
    select userid,statuskey,total_end_date,batch_end_date,dateadd(second,900,nearestdate),
    dateadd(second,900,batch_end_date) from cte2 where dateadd(second,15,batch_end_date)< total_end_date)
    select userid,statuskey,nearestdate,
    [count]= case 
    when batch_end_date<total_end_date then datediff(second,Start_date,batch_end_date)
    else datediff(second,Start_date,total_end_date) end
    from cte2
```

**OUTPUT**

- Output table is as per the requirement
  [image]

Comment: many thanks and it works for me but it takes a very long time to retrieve the data comparing to the same logic on excel (excel takes 3 min and sql takes 9 min) with the same date range and data

Comment: Check if this [sql script](https://dbfiddle.uk/ExPdp8TV) works better.

Comment: dear, you code is working very well but there's a very small difference with 1 sec and i think it's happen because of rounding , i need to to change the (datetime) to (smalldatetime) for the below two lines

`nearestdate= cast(floor(cast([start_date] as float)*(24*4))/(24*4) as datetime),
batch_end_date=cast(ceiling(cast([start_date] as float)*(24*4))/(24*4) as datetime)`

but when i try to do this i found error message (Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "StatusDateTimeGMT" of recursive query "cte2".)

Comment: Create this column **StatusDateTimeGMT** with smalldatetime . Then try changing datetime to smalldatetime in those two lines. I hope this will work.

Comment: i think that the issue because the datetime with Msec, so when i try to use your logic, it didn't round correctly, i used 'smalldatetime 'but it gives me not accurate data with 1 sec, so can you advise me.

Comment: Which method are you using?

Comment: The second one "Alternate approach-Method2"